# Load view from different states in one view and same url angularjs ui-router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I need to load two different views in two different ui-view(s) with different states but same url. I made an example which works but if I change **app.header.view.index** to **index** it stops working, I want to use different states because I have multiple modules which loads in one project and each one of them doesn't know anything about the others so each one of them has own routing and own states but they can load different view in same url. for example all of them has header module which loads header and menus and etc.. for all pages. let me know if I didn't explain clearly.

https://jsfiddle.net/navid_gh/jwjbd1j4/

**html**

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="body"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

**js**

```
(function(angular) {
  angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);

  angular.module('myApp').config(appConfig);

  appConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];

  function appConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

    $stateProvider
      .state('app', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        views: {
          'body@': {
            template: "1"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.header', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
          "header@": {
            template: "<div ui-view='menu'></div><div ui-view='sidebar'></div>"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.header.view', {
        url: '',
        abstract: true,
        views: {
          "menu": {
            template: "2"
          },
          "sidebar": {
            template: "3"
          }
        }
      })
      .state('app.header.view.index', {
        url: '/',
        views: {
          'content@': {
            template: "4"
          }
        }
      });
  }
})(angular);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so sure to understand what you want but i can tell you that what you have writtent works as it has been written.

When you change index to be top level state, your ui-router match '/' thanks to the otherwise. Since index is not anymore a child of app, that's why you have only the number '4' that appear.

If you want to have seperate module that has the same structure i suggest you to use a provider which register your module and then generate your state/views to make them like this :

```
angular.module('myApp', ["ui.router"]);
angular.module('myApp').config(appConfig);
appConfig.$inject = ['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider'];
function appConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

$stateProvider
  .state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '',
    views: {
      header@': {
        template: '<div ui-view="module1"></div><div ui-view="module2"></div>'
      },
      content@': {
        template: '<div ui-view="module1"></div><div ui-view="module2"></div>'
        }
    }
  })
  .state('app.header.module1', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "@": {
        template: "1"
      }
    }
  })
    .state('app.header.module2, {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "@": {
        template: "2"
      }
    }
  })
    .state('app.content.module1', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "@": {
        template: "3"
      }
    }
  })
    .state('app.content.module2', {
    url: '',
    views: {
      "@": {
        template: "4"
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Where the template of app state would be : (static version, you could use a list and a ng-repeat on your module list) .

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ui-view="header"></div>
    <div ui-view="content"></div>
</body>
```

JSFiddle isn't answering but can you tell me at least if it's looks like to what you're looking for ?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me clear it. For instance I have HeaderModule, AdminModule, DashboardModule and CoreModule

In CoreModule I defined the index.html and the structure and Admin and Dashboard have own content view ( not header )

So I want to load HeaderModule view in both of them.

If I go to /admin it should load CoreView ( <div ui-view="header"></div> .... ) and load Header and bind it to ui-view="header" then load the content of admin panel to ui-view="content". @Walfrat

Comment: Do you have the need to be able to have different header module ? Or do you jsut have one and the other module has only content that change ?

Comment: Actually for now I have just one and the other just change the content but in some cases the module changes the header. If you have any solution please tell me about both of them. @Walfrat